# Why does the code permute delimiters

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am new to Excel VBA and learning by modifying/changing existing code. I tried some code that takes a string and gives me the next permutation. My data is in cell A1 and consists of numbers delimited by commas. It treats the delimiters as part of the data. If I try to permute double digits (10 etc.) it would treat those as 1 and 0.

```
Function nextPerm(s As String)
' inspired by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352203/generating-permutations-lazily
' this produces the "next" permutation
' it allows one to step through all possible iterations without having to have them
' all in memory at the same time
    Dim L As Integer, ii As Integer, jj As Integer
    Dim c() As Byte, temp As Byte

    L = Len(s)

    If StrComp(s, "**done**") = 0 Or StrComp(s, "") = 0 Then
        nextPerm = ""
        Exit Function
    End If

' convert to byte array... more compact to manipulate
    ReDim c(1 To L)
    For ii = 1 To L
        c(ii) = Asc(Mid(s, ii, 1))
    Next ii

' find the largest "tail":
    For ii = L - 1 To 1 Step -1
        If c(ii) < c(ii + 1) Then Exit For
    Next ii

' if we complete the loop without break, ii will be zero
    If ii = 0 Then
        nextPerm = "**done**"
        Exit Function
    End If

' find the smallest value in the tail that is larger than c(ii)
' take advantage of the fact that tail is sorted in reverse order
    For jj = L To ii + 1 Step -1
        If c(jj) > c(ii) Then
            ' swap elements
            temp = c(jj)
            c(jj) = c(ii)
            c(ii) = temp
            Exit For
        End If
    Next jj

' now reverse the characters from ii+1 to the end:
    nextPerm = ""
    For jj = 1 To ii
        nextPerm = nextPerm & Chr(c(jj))
    Next jj
    For jj = L To ii + 1 Step -1
        nextPerm = nextPerm & Chr(c(jj))
    Next jj
End Function
```

What do I need to change to make this work?

Comment: I guess I forgot to ask:" What do I need to change?"

Comment: Can you give an example of the data you're using the function on? And the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is version for comma separated lists:

```
Function nextPerm2(s As String)
' inspired by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352203/generating-permutations-lazily
' this produces the "next" permutation
' it allows one to step through all possible iterations without having to have them
' all in memory at the same time
    Dim L As Integer, ii As Integer, jj As Integer
    Dim c() As Variant, temp As Variant

    L = Len(s)

    If StrComp(s, "**done**") = 0 Or StrComp(s, "") = 0 Then
        nextPerm2 = ""
        Exit Function
    End If

' convert to byte array... more compact to manipulate
    arr = Split(s, ",")

    ReDim c(1 To UBound(arr) + 1)
    For ii = 1 To UBound(arr) + 1
        c(ii) = arr(ii - 1)
    Next ii
    L = UBound(arr) + 1
' find the largest "tail":
    For ii = L - 1 To 1 Step -1
        If c(ii) < c(ii + 1) Then Exit For
    Next ii

' if we complete the loop without break, ii will be zero
    If ii = 0 Then
        nextPerm2 = "**done**"
        Exit Function
    End If

' find the smallest value in the tail that is larger than c(ii)
' take advantage of the fact that tail is sorted in reverse order
    For jj = L To ii + 1 Step -1
        If c(jj) > c(ii) Then
            ' swap elements
            temp = c(jj)
            c(jj) = c(ii)
            c(ii) = temp
            Exit For
        End If
    Next jj

' now reverse the characters from ii+1 to the end:
    nextPerm2 = ""
    For jj = 1 To ii
        nextPerm2 = nextPerm2 & c(jj) & ","
    Next jj
    For jj = L To ii + 1 Step -1
        nextPerm2 = nextPerm2 & c(jj) & ","
    Next jj

    If Right(nextPerm2, 1) = "," Then nextPerm2 = Left(nextPerm2, Len(nextPerm2) - 1)
End Function
```

The parsing uses `Split()` and there are other changes.

**Not fully tested!**

[image]

Comment: I was able to use this Macro and get all 120 Permutations of 5 numbers. It will take me a while to find examples and review the steps involved in order to understand it better. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I haven't changed the algorithm in the initial posts:

- C++: [Generating permutations lazily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352203/generating-permutations-lazily) (SO link)
- VBA: [Permutating an array in VBA to compute the Shapley-Shubik power index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14755620/permutating-an-array-in-vba-to-compute-the-shapley-shubik-power-index/14756999#14756999) (SO link)
- Or initial article: [C++ Algorithms: next_permutation()](http://marknelson.us/2002/03/01/next-permutation/) (External link)

but I did modify the VBA code to more descriptive variable names, and to allow for delimiters as parameters in the initial string:

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ShowPerm()

    With Sheet1
        .Range("B1") = nextPerm2(.Range("A1"))
        .Range("B2") = nextPerm2(.Range("A2"), " ")
        .Range("B3") = nextPerm2(.Range("A3"), " ")
        .Range("B4") = nextPerm2(.Range("A4"))
    End With

    'if A1 = "3,2,5,4,1"    Then B1 = "3,4,1,2,5"
    'if A2 = "3 222 5 4 1"  Then B2 = "3 4 1 222 5"
    'if A3 = "1"            Then B3 = "**done**"
    'if A4 = "2"            Then B4 = "**done**"

End Sub
```

---

```
Public Function nextPerm2(ByVal strIni As String, _
                          Optional ByVal delim As String = ",") As String

'inspired by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352203/generating-permutations-lazily
'this produces the "next" permutation it allows one to step through all possible
'iterations without having to have them all in memory at the same time

    Dim arr As Variant, arrSz As Long, i As Long, j As Long, tmp As Byte

    If strIni = "**done**" Or Len(strIni) = 0 Then Exit Function

    arr = Split(strIni, delim)      'convert to array

    arrSz = UBound(arr)

    For i = 0 To arrSz
        arr(i) = Trim(arr(i))       'clean-up white-spaces from each item
    Next i
    For i = arrSz - 1 To 0 Step -1  'find the largest "tail"
        If arr(i) < arr(i + 1) Then Exit For
    Next i
    If i = 0 Or i = -1 Then         'if loop complete, i is 0; if i = -1, arrSz = 0
        nextPerm2 = "**done**"
        Exit Function
    End If

    'find the smallest value in the tail that is larger than arr(i)
    'take advantage of the fact that tail is sorted in reverse order
    For j = arrSz To i + 1 Step -1
        If arr(j) > arr(i) Then     'swap elements
            tmp = arr(j)
            arr(j) = arr(i)
            arr(i) = tmp
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j

    'now reverse the characters from i + 1 to the end
    nextPerm2 = vbNullString
    For j = 0 To i
        nextPerm2 = nextPerm2 & arr(j) & delim
    Next j
    For j = arrSz To i + 1 Step -1
        nextPerm2 = nextPerm2 & arr(j) & delim
    Next j

    nextPerm2 = Left(nextPerm2, Len(nextPerm2) - 1) 'remove last delim

End Function
```

---

Comment: Thank you very much. It will take me a while to review it and compare to the original code. I see that you changed it to array and that you split for the permutation and then return the delimiter. Thank you and all the others for your help. I am sure I'll be back for more advice.

Comment: Yes - the initial byte array didn't fit this model (@Gary used the same approach)

Comment: I am not sure if I am doing something wrong but I was only able to get the first 24 Permutations starting with the first number.